# Windows very slow after unexpected reboot

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, hibernate, reboot

I got tired while working, so I put my computer in hibernation with a lot of windows open. At night my computer rebooted itself for some reason. It was running when I woke up. And now some actions take a horribly long time to load when before everything opened instantly.

My computer is very fast. I have a samsung 830 series SSD and AMD Phenom 2 X4 955 processor.

Now it takes a minute to open a link from an email, to open customization options or the screen resolution window, to open microsoft Word, to open a webbrowser or to open some installers. Previously these actions would complete almost instantly.

Why is this happening? And is there something I can do about it?

Thank you very much!

Windows log notes:

```
Het besturingssysteem wordt afgesloten op systeemtijd ‎2013‎-‎01‎-‎10T02:24:06.640451600Z.  10-01-2013 03.24.06
Het besturingssysteem wordt gestart op systeemtijd ‎2013‎-‎01‎-‎10T07:47:51.125599300Z. 10-01-2013 08.47.51
Het systeem is uit de slaapstand gekomen.

Start van slaapstand: ‎2013‎-‎01‎-‎10T01:04:28.197652700Z
Einde van slaapstand: ‎2013‎-‎01‎-‎10T02:01:05.294102600Z 03:01:06

Oorzaak van einde slaapstand: Onbekend
Installatie voltooid: de volgende update is geïnstalleerd: Beveiligingsupdate voor Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 op Windows 7 en Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 voor x64-systemen (KB2736422)
Installatie voltooid: de volgende update is geïnstalleerd: Definitie-update voor Microsoft Office 2010 (KB982726) 32-bits versie
Installatie voltooid: de volgende update is geïnstalleerd: KB2736428:     Beveiligingsupdate voor Microsoft .NET Framework 4 op Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2 voor x64-systemen
Installatie voltooid: de volgende update is geïnstalleerd: KB890830: Windows-programma voor het verwijderen van schadelijke software voor x64-systemen- januari 2013
Installatie voltooid: de volgende update is geïnstalleerd: KB2742595:     Beveiligingsupdate voor Microsoft .NET Framework 4 op Windows XP, Windows Server 2003,     Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2 voor x64-systemen
Opnieuw opstarten vereist: de computer wordt over 15 minuten opnieuw opgestart om de   installatie van de volgende updates te voltooien: 
- Beveiligingsupdate voor Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 op Windows 7 en Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 voor x64-systemen (KB2736422)
- KB2778930: Beveiligingsupdate voor Windows 7 voor x64-systemen
- KB2786081: Update voor Windows 7 voor x64-systemen
- Definitie-update voor Microsoft Office 2010 (KB982726) 32-bits versie
- KB2726535: Update voor Windows 7 voor x64-systemen
- KB2736428: Beveiligingsupdate voor Microsoft .NET Framework 4 op Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2 voor x64-systemen
- Beveiligingsupdate voor Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 op Windows 7 en Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 voor x64-systemen (KB2742599)
- KB2773072: Update voor Windows 7 voor x64-systemen
- KB2786400: Update voor Windows 7 voor x64-systemen
- KB2785220: Beveiligingsupdate voor Windows 7 voor x64-systemen
- KB2757638: Beveiligingsupdate voor Windows 7 voor x64-systemen
- KB890830: Windows-programma voor het verwijderen van schadelijke soft
Er is een overgang naar afsluiting gestart.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try rebooting, simply. Sometimes, "stuff happens", and then you need to fix what executing itself wrongly by rebooting.

If that's not your solution or if you already did, find why the computer rebooted itself. If it's an update that installed itself, for example (because Windows 7, I think, like Vista, automatically reboots after installing an update, unless you ask it not to, and it's only valid to leave it on for 4 hours, after which you need to click again).

If there was an error during the installation of the update, that might explain your problem.

Also, if Windows Update forced the computer to reboot itself while your open windows were preventing it from doing so, because of unsaved data, and it did it anyway, well, that sounds like it might put errors in some places.

Anyway, if an update was installed, it's possible that you have a system restoration point before it, that was created automatically. You might want to go back to that and try updating again.

If that's not it, well, something else forced the reboot, and might have caused data losses or errors. For that, perhaps you can run utilities in an attempt to fix those errors. Defrag, chkdsk (warning! this can actually ruin a partition if you're unlucky, apparently, so, last resort only!), Windows "system repair", diagnostic stuff...

Also, as always with mysterious issues, it's always a good idea to run a malicious software scan, just in case.

Comment: Thanks Ariane! I have already rebooted and run the malicious software scan. But I will find out why it rebooted. I think it was for updates as you said. but why does this happen while the PC is in hibernation? Does it come out of hibernation to reboot itself for the windows updates?

Comment: Normally, it doesn't. Perhaps it had already installed the updates and was just about to show you the pop-up when you left. Perhaps it went out of hibernation just a few seconds after you put it into it (happens, sometimes). Maybe "something" woke it up, be it software or a cat. Maybe Windows Update has some sort of super priority. Maybe you put it into hibernation -during- update installation, and that seriously messed with everything. I wouldn't know. I never ever use sleep or hibernation modes.

Comment: Damn. I have found some windows log notes about the sudden reboot, but accidentally placed them in the wrong post. I cannot edit the post anymore, could you please remove them for me?

Comment: Anyway, the lognotes show me that windows is rebooted because of windows updates. Among the updates where updates for microsoft office and .net framework. Maybe those explain why windows is so slow?

Comment: I don't understand the language it's in, but it's not important. Yes, it's most probably not a coincidence. I seriously doubt the updates themselves are the problem (those aren't even remotely core components of the OS), but I think the forced reboot messed things up. Use the system restore point for that update if you have one. And sure, I removed your mistaken edit. ^^

Comment: In the end, it appears that running SFC /Scannow followed by a restart fixed the problems. Now my links and programs open fast again :) Thx for all your tips! I can always use them the next time a situation like this occurrs ;) Thx Ariane!